# PHP Echo HTML from class and styling

Tags: php, html, css

I am having issues `echo`-ing a large amount of html from a php class and then styling it.

It seems as if unless I add breaks no CSS gets applied.  Is that correct?  What is the best practice?

Below is an example; there is a lot more that gets echoed then this.

```
$retStr = '<div class="someClass"><div class="anotherClass"><h3>Hello</h3><p class="someP">Whats up</p><img src="someLocation"/><a href="somePlace" class="someA">Hey Now</a></div></div>';
return $retStr;
```

VS.

```
$retStr = '<div class="someClass">' .PHP_EOL;
$retStr .= '<div class="anotherClass">' .PHP_EOL;
$retStr .= '<h3>Hello</h3>' .PHP_EOL;
$retStr .= '<p class="someP">Whats up</p>' .PHP_EOL;
$retStr .= '<img src="someLocation"/>' .PHP_EOL;
$retStr .= '<a href="somePlace" class="someA">Hey Now</a>' .PHP_EOL;
$retStr .= '</div>' .PHP_EOL;
$retStr .= '</div>' .PHP_EOL;
return $retStr;
```

Thanks!

Comment: whitespace generally has no significance whatsoever to html or css. And you'd have to show what your css is before we can tell you anything about what MIGHT be wrong with it. we cannot read your mind.

Comment: No it makes no difference at all, except that second one is more readable. CSS shouldnt be a problem either. And you dont have to insert newlines, HTML is not like Python where and whitespace or newline is important.

Comment: Thanks Marc B.  So I set it up locally, and then in the class that is hosted (on the server), I actually iterate through these divs in a loop but no styles really get applied.  The CSS works locally but gets wonky unless I add line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Php echo don`t have javascript problems :)

You can store book long text in one variable and echo it without any break lines.

If you can show more code. It would be much easier to find solution to your problem.

Check if css is actualy applied on the site (use Firefox Firebug for it).

Comment: I "inspect" with chrome and the style is there.  However, unless I have breaks it gets all crunched.

Comment: Are you passing this data through javascript?
Maybe you can provide some link where we can check out how it looks.

Maybe try very weird thing and pass <style> also through function.

Comment: Nope I am not passing it through any JS.  I am wondering if it is a server configuration...  Locally on my mac it renders fine no matter the spacing.  However, on my hosted server it gets wonky.